# Python replace up to \n in a function

Tags: python, regex, replace

I want to use a function that does the following:

- it takes 2 parameters, a string s, and an integer n
- it should return a string composed by

  - "#" n times
  - "\n"
  - the right number of "=", so that the sum of "#" and "=" is equal to the length of s (\n doesn't count)

What I have so far:

```
def warpbar(text, lineLength):
    if len(text) <= lineLength:
        return text
    else:
        return text[:lineLength] + '\n' + warpbar(text[lineLength:], lineLength)
```

So `warpbar("zzzzzzzzzzz",4)` returns

- "z" 4 times
- "\n"
- "z" 4 times
- "\n"
- "z" 3 times

It should returns

- "#" 4 times
- "\n"
- "=" 7 times

How can I change the part before and after the \n?

Comment: What are the rules of how to replace? Increment all the integer values by 2?

Comment: No, the values don't matter.

Comment: So how do you know what the output should be? How did `111` go to `333`? What is the rule to change out the value?

Comment: You still didn't say where foo and bar came from.

Comment: @GreenAsJade why does it matter? Anyway, I added an illustration of what I am trying to explain.

Comment: Can't you just replace the whole string? `a="zzz\nzzz"` then `a="foo\nbar"`?

Comment: @fredtantini No, because zzz\nzzz is the output of a function.

Comment: @octosquidopus Then `a=functionThatReturnZZZ()` and later `a="foo\nbar"`?

Comment: @fredtantini question updated with more context. I cannot simply assign a new value, because I want to keep the original amount of characters, which can vary.

Comment: @octosquidopus It's a little bit more clear, but what should be the result if it's on 3,4,more lines?

Comment: @fredtantini You mean if there is more than one \n ? That will never happen. Sure I can modify the function. The way I use the function, lineLength is always the same value, so there is never more than one \n.

Comment: @octosquidopus Your function states otherwise What should be the result of `warpbar("zzzzzzzzzz", 2)`?

Comment: The function could be simplified by stripping the variable lineLength, because its value never changes, and it will always yield a string in the form zzzzz\nxxxxxx, although the length of what follows \n can vary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66128/discussion-between-octosquidopus-and-fredtantini).

Comment: I think it was clear that no-one could understand what you were trying to do, that's why you needed to say.    At last your question makes sense - it's much better with examples and your current code.   You might want to start accepting some answers to your questions, though, if you want to continue getting good help ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the multiplication on string, so

```
def warpbar(text, lineLength):
   n = len(text)
   return "#"*lineLength+"\n"+"="*(n-lineLength)
```

returns what you want.

Comment: `split()` doesn't just split on newlines, though - `.split("\n")` would be better.

Comment: Indeed… I meant `splitlines`